# phpmyadmin change table engine when exporting in SQL formt

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb, myisam

I have a db schema with 10 tables in mysql. some of table has `innodb` engine, and some of table with `myisam`. 
However, when using phpmyadmin exporting the schema in SQL format, **it converts all tables engine to mysiam**.
So why phpmyadmin automatically change the tables engine?
How can I keep my tables engine the same when export with phpmyadmin?

Comment: Check if you are dumping the data as "structure and data" selected option when exporting using "Custom - display all possible options"

Comment: i did check the 'structure and data' option!

Comment: if possible can you please share the screenshot of settings of "Custom - display all possible options"

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are dumping the data as "structure and data" selected option when exporting using "Custom - display all possible options".